# my Bowens flashes not bouncing

Tags: studio-lighting

I am using Bowens prolite 100, sometimes one of the head will not bounce/sync with the other, even if I trigger the radio transmitter manually without the camera,
any idea. thank you

Comment: Do all of them use a radio receiver or do you trigger one and then use the photo cell to trigger the rest? Is it always the same head that is missing out? Or is it some certain position in your studio that seems to have an effect?